# Xcode Version 14.1 is removing custom keys from info.plist once url updated?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've noticed recently in xCode Version 14.1 , when i update Targets -> Info -> URL Types , any custom field in info.plist i've added early is being removed by xCode such as ATT or Facebook client token etc .

I've tried to close and reopen the project , also I've removed the xCode completely from my mac and reinstalled it still same issue .

is it possible a bug ! it is very risky to upload the app with missing info.plist keys to store  .

I've already reported this issue to apple still no response , but if anyone has same issue and managed to fixed!

Answer (score 0):

The Packaging collection of build settings has the build settings for automatically generating an Info.plist file.

To access the build settings,

1. Select your project from the left side of the project window to open the project editor.
2. Select the app target from the left side of the project editor.
3. Click the Build Settings button at the top of the project editor.
4. Typing Info.plist in the search field in the build settings list will show the build settings that deal with the Info.plist file.